# SQL inner join with blank entries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assuming that I have two tables

Machine Table

```
| id    | ip_address|
|-------|-----------|
|   1   |1.1.1.1    |
|   2   |1.1.1.2    |
|   3   |1.1.1.3    |
|   4   |1.1.1.4    |
```

Schedule Table

```
| id    | machine_id| reserved_date|user_id|
|-------|-----------|--------------|-------|
|  1    |    1      |  2019-10-31  |  1    |
|  2    |    2      |  2019-10-10  |  2    |
|  3    |    3      |  2019-10-31  |  4    |
```

Currently, the query that I have returns only the data that satisfies the where clause (which is to be expected) but what I need is to to be able to get all the machine from the machine table including the user_id from the schedule table that satisfies the where clause.

```
SELECT machine.ip_address, schedule.user_id  FROM machine 
INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.machine_id = machines_machine.id
WHERE schedule.reserved_date = '2019-10-31';
```

Expected result:

```
| ip_address | user_id |
|------------|---------|
| 1.1.1.1    | 1       |
| 1.1.1.2    |         |
| 1.1.1.3    | 4       |
| 1.1.1.4    |         |
```

I need to return all the machine from the machine table plus an extra column which only contain the user_id of the reservation that satisfies that date specified.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join the tables, move `WHERE` condition regarding the left-joined table columns to `ON`.

```
WITH Machines(id, ip_address) as (
 values 
    (1, '1.1.1.1')
   ,(2, '1.1.1.2')
   ,(3, '1.1.1.3')
   ,(4, '1.1.1.4')
),Schedule(id, machine_id, reserved_date, user_id) as (
 values 
    (1, 1, '2019-10-31', 1)
   ,(2, 2, '2019-10-10', 2)
   ,(3, 3, '2019-10-31', 4)
)
SELECT machines.ip_address, schedule.user_id  
FROM machines 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON schedule.machine_id = machines.id
                  AND schedule.reserved_date = '2019-10-31';
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e15a3e51ec4b81672ee8282f45d2abc9)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried your solution but it only displays the a subset of the entire machine.

Comment: See the updated answer with the sample data, it returns all machines, 4 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT machine. ip_address, schedule. user_id  
FROM machine 
LEFT JOIN schedule 
ON schedule. machine_id = machine. machine_id 
WHERE schedule. reserved_date='2019-10-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

use left join instade of innerjoin

```
SELECT machine.ip_address, schedule.user_id  FROM machine 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON schedule.machine_id = machines_machine.id
WHERE schedule.reserved_date = '2019-10-31';
```